# servicestack disrupting MVC routes when using as a referenced project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have created a servicestack MVC project, this I use as the main API for the database.
because I want to access the models in my code I have also added a reference to this project in my MVC Views Project and Controllers project.

However I am having real problems when I run my project [ the web site project ]
in that ServiceStack thinks it owns my solution, and takes over all request, and is then unable to resolve my routes.

I have added routes in the web projects global file, I have also tried adding these routes to the servicestack project, but still unable to resolve.

here is the error:

```
[ResolutionException: Required dependency of type      uyr.print.controllers.Controllers.UsersController could not be resolved.]
    Funq.Container.ThrowMissing(String serviceName) in        C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\Funq\Container.cs:297
   Funq.Container.GetEntry(String serviceName, Boolean throwIfMissing) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\Funq\Container.cs:275
   Funq.Container.ResolveImpl(String name, Boolean throwIfMissing) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\Funq\Container.cs:112
  Funq.Container.ResolveNamed(String name) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\Funq\Container.Overloads.cs:283
  Funq.Container.Resolve() in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\Funq\Container.Overloads.cs:230
   lambda_method(Closure , Container ) +41
    ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ContainerResolveCache.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean tryResolve) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\ServiceHost\ContainerResolveCache.cs:62
   ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ContainerResolveCache.CreateInstance(Type type) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\ServiceHost\ContainerResolveCache.cs:37
   ServiceStack.Mvc.FunqControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext   requestContext, Type controllerType) in   C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3\Mvc\FunqControllerFactory.cs:38
    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +232
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +13
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +124
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970356
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction here, it would be much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in that ServiceStack thinks it owns my solution, and takes over all request, and is then unable to resolve my routes.

ServiceStack doesn't own anything you don't explicitly tell it to.

> ServiceStack ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new
>   FunqControllerFactory(container));

This tells MVC to use ServiceStack built-in Funq IOC to resolve and auto-wire **all MVC Controllers**. Typically if you have ServiceStack + MVC running together in the same project you want to use the same IOC to resolve ServiceStack services and MVC Controller dependencies.

Uncomment that line if you don't want MVC Controllers to use ServiceStack's IOC.

#### Handler Path Configuration

In the Web.config you also tell ServiceStack [exactly what path you want ServiceStack to handle](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#rootpath).

These are the only 2 places where ServiceStack is configured to handle requests. If you don't have any of these configurations than the ServiceStack dlls are benign and doesn't have any effect on your project. i.e. There are no HTTP Modules registered that invasively attempts to hi-jack requests.

The only library here with that problem is MVC where it thinks it owns the whole solution, even after telling IIS to delegate all `/api` requests to ServiceStack (with the Web.Config) you also need to tell MVC to explicitly ignore these routes with:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");
```

Otherwise it will try to handle them.

Comment: nice one mythz,  if i uncomment these lines, will i still be able to use the API with urls too.   basically I have a base model, inherited by all models in serviceStack, this takes in a username, pass and api key and i then authorise all API request.   my MVC controllers project has a simple handler to add credentials and then make a URL request or post to the API URL ( will be separate URL )

Comment: FunqControllerFactory is only used to share 1 IOC between MVC + SS. Handler config + MVC IngoreRoute will still let SS still handle `/api` requests.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using the [Funq DI container](http://funq.codeplex.com/). It's attempting to find a dependency that you haven't created during the initialization of Funq. Without knowing how Funq works (never heard of it before now) or what your code base looks like, that's about as helpful as we can be for now.

Comment: //Set MVC to use the same Funq IOC as ServiceStack
   ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));    is how servicestack implement's routing,   but I am not running a servicestack project, I am simply using it as a reference, but the service is taking over, therefore not allowing me to reference any code at all within a servicestack project, also who do you mean by WE ?